# How to workaround PostGIS 2.5.1 St_Contains and St_Intersects seemingly incorrect

Tags: postgis

I generate rectangles in several steps and store them in my layer `f`. I want to check some points `p` are inside `f`.

I've been using `ST_Contains` successfully for that numerous times but here apparently something is working wrong. My valid rectangle seem to return no result despite the `p` distance being zero to the f polygons. Creating a zero-sized buffer around the geometry fixes the issue.

Some query results:

```sql
SELECT ST_Contains(f.geom, p.geom) AS cont, 
        ST_Intersects(f.geom, p.geom), 
        ST_Contains(ST_buffer(f.geom, 0), p.geom), 
        ST_IsValid(f.geom) FROM p, f 
    WHERE ST_Distance(p.geom, f.geom) = 0;
```

Returns 24 rows of the same result:

```
 cont | st_intersects | st_contains | st_isvalid 
------+---------------+-------------+------------
 f    | f             | t           | t
 f    | f             | t           | t
 f    | f             | t           | t
 f    | f             | t           | t
...
```

You might want to inspect the geometries, here are some WKT.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880254.749528626 2093967.93325517)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880282.924927942 2094078.47917296)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880247.239262913 2093924.13757967)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880259.292533207 2093998.30081985)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880274.861655091 2094050.08322417)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880235.246430151 2093873.17666099)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880241.881227955 2094125.57085486)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880293.085816423 2094119.0045371)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880280.710748428 2093963.65224477)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880271.883837544 2094023.93306988)
 POLYGON((880129.684433414 2093867.66419744,880323.23794347 2093822.91225742,880395.643963026 2094136.07050777,880202.09045297 2094180.8224478,880129.684433414 2093867.66419744))    | POINT(880240.641842143 2093897.54591352)
 POLYGON((880239.930760153 2094256.42447412,880351.22264682 2094246.79152989,880366.827596573 2094427.07953528,880255.535709905 2094436.71247951,880239.930760153 2094256.42447412))  | POINT(880312.344754627 2094404.83852163)
 POLYGON((880239.930760153 2094256.42447412,880351.22264682 2094246.79152989,880366.827596573 2094427.07953528,880255.535709905 2094436.71247951,880239.930760153 2094256.42447412))  | POINT(880299.646589879 2094298.62966665)
 POLYGON((880239.930760153 2094256.42447412,880351.22264682 2094246.79152989,880366.827596573 2094427.07953528,880255.535709905 2094436.71247951,880239.930760153 2094256.42447412))  | POINT(880307.111596792 2094384.87481506)
 POLYGON((880239.930760153 2094256.42447412,880351.22264682 2094246.79152989,880366.827596573 2094427.07953528,880255.535709905 2094436.71247951,880239.930760153 2094256.42447412))  | POINT(880314.777435303 2094354.81242228)
 POLYGON((880217.493080654 2094349.33971867,880389.905207068 2094319.92725517,880437.491004786 2094598.86915904,880265.078878372 2094628.28162254,880217.493080654 2094349.33971867)) | POINT(880336.390622857 2094506.74079485)
 POLYGON((880217.493080654 2094349.33971867,880389.905207068 2094319.92725517,880437.491004786 2094598.86915904,880265.078878372 2094628.28162254,880217.493080654 2094349.33971867)) | POINT(880312.344754627 2094404.83852163)
 POLYGON((880217.493080654 2094349.33971867,880389.905207068 2094319.92725517,880437.491004786 2094598.86915904,880265.078878372 2094628.28162254,880217.493080654 2094349.33971867)) | POINT(880324.610461566 2094453.16928367)
 POLYGON((880217.493080654 2094349.33971867,880389.905207068 2094319.92725517,880437.491004786 2094598.86915904,880265.078878372 2094628.28162254,880217.493080654 2094349.33971867)) | POINT(880336.165772925 2094544.47430614)
 POLYGON((880217.493080654 2094349.33971867,880389.905207068 2094319.92725517,880437.491004786 2094598.86915904,880265.078878372 2094628.28162254,880217.493080654 2094349.33971867)) | POINT(880307.111596792 2094384.87481506)
 POLYGON((880217.493080654 2094349.33971867,880389.905207068 2094319.92725517,880437.491004786 2094598.86915904,880265.078878372 2094628.28162254,880217.493080654 2094349.33971867)) | POINT(880347.65180718 2094570.5975052)
 POLYGON((880217.493080654 2094349.33971867,880389.905207068 2094319.92725517,880437.491004786 2094598.86915904,880265.078878372 2094628.28162254,880217.493080654 2094349.33971867)) | POINT(880361.806155674 2094461.21634896)
 POLYGON((880217.493080654 2094349.33971867,880389.905207068 2094319.92725517,880437.491004786 2094598.86915904,880265.078878372 2094628.28162254,880217.493080654 2094349.33971867)) | POINT(880314.777435303 2094354.81242228)
 POLYGON((880217.493080654 2094349.33971867,880389.905207068 2094319.92725517,880437.491004786 2094598.86915904,880265.078878372 2094628.28162254,880217.493080654 2094349.33971867)) | POINT(880247.996625299 2094380.16259736)
```

The geometry hexes:

```
0103000020B46B00000100000005000000740E6E5E03DC2A41F8D708AA2BF33F41FCB9D37986DD2A41C7B389E9FEF23F418F85B54917DE2A412ACC0C1238F43F4108DA4F2E94DC2A415AF08BD264F43F41740E6E5E03DC2A41F8D708AA2BF33F41
0103000020B46B0000010000000500000041988CDCDFDC2A410356AA6CB0F43F4197C3FE71BEDD2A41E9B3A1CAA6F43F41EEBCBAA7DDDD2A41836C5C145BF53F4198914812FFDC2A419D0E65B664F53F4141988CDCDFDC2A410356AA6CB0F43F41
0103000020B46B00000100000005000000491175FCB2DC2A418CCDF7560DF53F41034D77CF0BDE2A41559860EDEFF43F41B1FA64FB6ADE2A41003581DE06F63F41F7BE622812DD2A41376A184824F63F41491175FCB2DC2A418CCDF7560DF53F41
```

I also have checked the SRID. The buffer test convinced me it's a PostGIS bug. Is the issue documented somewhere ? Is there cleaner workaround ? I'm running PostGIS 2.5.1.

EDIT: I have compared the geometry initially and as the result of ST_Buffer. The point order is different: if my polygon is ABCDA initially it's ADCBA as the result of `ST_Buffer(geom, 0)`. So I suspect the direct or indirect ordering of the polygon might affect the result of `ST_Contains`

Comment: Can you make a test with a newer PostGIS?

Comment: I'm not sure I can, no. I would need to build a newer docker image for our program who handles the data building, to reproduce the exact conditions on index / geometry construction history etc. these may be important I know I changed something in the way these polygons are built that affected the result on this, so I suspect I would need to transpose the whole program in a newer postgis to test reproduction.

Comment: If there is a bug in PostGIS 2.5.1 it is very unlikely that it will be fixed. For debugging a small PostgreSQL dump might be the best option, translation into WKT is not exact. Or the hex presentation of "select geometry" `"0106000020E6100000010000000103000000010000000C000000F7B182DF8640...`

Comment: If that can help I will add to the question the geometry dumps

Comment: I get correct results on PostGIS >= 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the test. I might just try to push for an upgrade of our postgis.